# .index of a Datalist Array coming up as "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm trying to have a datalist that was populated from an array in javascript tell me what part of the array was clicked on.

I did a little troubleshooting with my bit of code and it turns out my arrays are all reporting undefined or 0.

I've started using jQuery as it is a little cleaner and easier to understand, so here is my current formula to send me an alert if I select something from an array:

Here is the html:

```
<input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="Update()">
    <datalist id="courses" name="courseDatalist">
        <!--Filled in script-->                 
    </datalist>
```

Here is the js/jQuery:

```
//Defines Course Names as an array and sets to the datalist
var courseNames = ["Survey Design and Data Analysis","Masters thesis Research","Enhancing Teaching Skills","Evaluation and Assessment","Strategies for Dealing with the Problem Learner","Medical Writing and Presentation Skills (Online)","Topics in Medical Education and Medical Education Research","Making the Most of Mentoring","Teaching Practicum: Outpatient Teaching","Teaching Practicum: Inpatient Teaching","Teaching Practicum: Classroom Teaching","Teaching Communication Skills","Seminar Series in Medical Education","Introduction to Systematic Reviews and Meta-Analyses"];
var list = $('#courses')[0];

//Creates an option element for each item in the array    
courseNames.forEach(function(item){
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = item;
    list.appendChild(option);
});

//Once an option is selected, tell which index number was selected
function Update() {
    $("input[name=courseInput]").change(function(){
        alert($(this).index());
    });
}
```

Now, if I change the last section from .index to .val, it does tell me the correct value of whatever option I selected.

Any idea why it wouldn't be accessing the array index number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your accessing the `this` in `Update` function your are accessing the input you created in your `forEach` loop not the array. If you would like to get the array index from the array above you would have to do something like this.

```
     function Update() {
       $("input[name=courseInput]").change(function(){
         // courseNames is the array you defined
         // $(this).val() returns a string in that array
         // indexOf looks for that string in the array
         courseNames.indexOf($(this).val());
       });
      }
```

indexOf doc: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: You bet, anytime!

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code. You should check the value from the courseNames.
I hope this what you are expecting.

```js
var courseNames = ["Survey Design and Data Analysis","Masters thesis Research","Enhancing Teaching Skills","Evaluation and Assessment","Strategies for Dealing with the Problem Learner","Medical Writing and Presentation Skills (Online)","Topics in Medical Education and Medical Education Research","Making the Most of Mentoring","Teaching Practicum: Outpatient Teaching","Teaching Practicum: Inpatient Teaching","Teaching Practicum: Classroom Teaching","Teaching Communication Skills","Seminar Series in Medical Education","Introduction to Systematic Reviews and Meta-Analyses"];
        var list = $('#courses')[0];

    //Creates an option element for each item in the array    
courseNames.forEach(function(item){
           var option = document.createElement('option');
           option.value = item;
           list.appendChild(option);
        });

   //Once an option is selected, tell which index number was selected
      function Update() {
      $("input[name=courseInput]").change(function(){
      alert(courseNames.indexOf($(this).val()));
      });
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input list="courses" name="courseInput" placeholder="Course" oninput="Update()">
      <datalist id="courses" name="courseDatalist">
        <!--Filled in script-->                 
      </datalist>
```